# Is it possible to use the SunPKCS11 provider to talk to a TPM2.0 chip using TPM2-PK11 library?

Tags: java, tpm

I have a TPM 2.0 chip which contains an RSA signing key (AIK) and I would like to sign a message using Java and I was wondering whether it would be possible to use the [SunPKCS11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.html#GUID-6DA72F34-6C6A-4F7D-ADBA-5811576A9331) provider to interface with [TPM2-PK11](https://github.com/irtimmer/tpm2-pk11)?

Comment: This question is specific to an uncommon software library; I recommend that you ask the software vendors, as you are unlikely to get an answer here.

Comment: The software you linked seems to be not maintained anymore. There is a [brand new pkcs11 provider](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-pkcs11)  (being developed by the developers of the TSS). It's just not released, yet. You might want to have a look at it.